# Proving an ideal in polynomial ring is idempotent

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be *non-Noetherian* commutative ring, and $I<A[X]$ an ideal, such that $A[X]/I\cong\mathbb{Z}$.

Is there a way to prove $I$ is idempotent, beside finding a set that span $I$ and trying to factor each of its elements?

(I'm aware that for general $A$ that may be the case. I'm hoping for shortcuts that may depend on the structure of $A$.)

**Edit**: I didn't claim this is true in general. I asked that **when** this is true, and in this case - **how** to prove it without trying to factor each generator of the ideal.

Comment: I don't think this is true. Take $A = \Bbb{Z}[x_1, x_2, \ldots]$. Then $A$ is not Noetherian. Now if you take $I$ to be the ideal in $A[X]$ generated by $\{X, x_1, x_2, \ldots \}$, then $A[X]/I \cong \Bbb{Z}$, but $I$ is not idempotent: $X \not\in I^2$.

Comment: @RobArthan Shouldn't your comment be edited as an answer?

Comment: @AnneBauval: thanks I was just awaiting a sanity check in case I'd missed something. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your conjecture isn't true: take $A = \Bbb{Z}[x_1, x_2, \ldots]$. Then $A$ is not Noetherian: if you take $I_n$ to be the ideal generated by $\{ x_1, \ldots, x_n \}$, then $I_1 \subset I_2 \subset \ldots$ is a strictly increasing ascending sequence of ideals.

Now if you take $I$ to be the ideal in $A[X]$ generated by $\{X, x_1,x_2, \ldots\}$, then $A[X]/I \cong \Bbb{Z}$, but $I$ is not idempotent: $X \in I$ and $X \not\in I^2$, so $I^2 \neq I$.